# Relation between Rayleigh and exponential distribution in the following?

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I am reading a paper. In the following image, as I understand, the transition lengths should be exponentially distributed. However, the author's claim it to be Rayleigh distributed.
Also, what does eq. 1 suggest (My idea is that the Transition-lengths $l$ are exponentially distributed with intensity $\lambda$, but then why do we have $\pi l^2$)

[image]

Comment: If you differentiate 1 you should probably find the rayleigh distribution....

Comment: Can you comment on why the authors would have considered Rayleigh distribution? As I know, transition lengths could follow exponential distribution instead!

Comment: I actually just know that you obtain the probability density by differentiating the cumulative density and that the kind of probability density you would find above is definitely rayleigh beyond that I have no idea about the subject matter and its relevance here. But from what I could glean from the first sentence is simply that there are many ways of modelling transition lengths and for the purpose of the text only i.i.d transition lengths are chosen which would mean subsequently (from the i.i.d assumption) that transition lengths are rayleigh distributed...hope this helps.